# Schedule computation for date field date.today() in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

I created a model as a history log for employees transfers between company departments so I created a wizard that pass new department location and another some information between them Transfer Date (date_from) and date_to .. I need to set field date_to=date.today() I need to know if there is a method to make it scheduled computed everyday automatically.
[image]

```
    def _prepare_transfer_history(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    return {
        'employee_id': self.employee_id.id,
        'work_loc_from': self.employee_id.work_location_id.id,
        'work_loc_to': self.location_to.id,
        'date_from': date.today(),
        # 'date_to': ,
        'salary': self.salary,
        }

   @api.model_create_multi
   def create(self, vals):
      transfers = super(TransferOperationWizard, self).create(vals)
      for transfer in transfers:
        if transfer.employee_id.work_location_id != transfer.location_to.id:
             self.env['employee.transfer.history'].create(transfer._prepare_transfer_history())
            transfer.employee_id.work_location_id = transfer.location_to.id
     return transfers
```